# Split Data for certain condition In JavaScript Pentaho

Tags: javascript, database, if-statement, substring, pentaho

I have a column in csv file named event_name and I am using Modified Java Script Value step to create new columns if the first character of event_name fufill conditions , for example :

event_name ="app_connection: connection_start_time = 10/05/2018 17:29:26: connection_end_time = 10/05/2018 17:29:29: connection_duration_in_seconds = 3"

```
           ==> event = app_connection
           ==> connection_start_time = 10/05/2018 17:29:26
           ==> connection_end_time = 10/05/2018 17:29:29
           ==> connection_duration_in_seconds = 3
```

if it's :                event_name ="scene_access"

```
==> event = scene_access
```

I tried this code but it doesn't seem to change anything :

```
            if(event_name.substr(0,3).equals("app"))
             {
               var event = event_name.substring(0,14);
               var connection_start_time = event_name.substr(40,59);
               var connection_end_time = event_name.substr(83,102);
               var connection_duration_in_seconds = event_name.substr(137,139);
               }
               else
                {
                  event_name = event_name;
                 }
```

If you could give me a hint or explaining what I'm missing will be a huge help.
Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I tried the field in the substring function, and in the substr function the sintaxis should be substr(string, position_from, number_of_characters).

With this change the code should be:

```
if(substr(event_name,0,3).equals("app"))
         {
           var event = substr(event_name,0,14);
           var connection_start_time = substr(event_name,40,19);
           var connection_end_time = substr(event_name,83,19);
           var connection_duration_in_seconds = substr(event_name,137,1);
           }
           else
            {
              event_name = event_name;
             }
```

After this press the button "Get variables" to make available the fields in the output of the step.